Prove that $|a|\leqρ$ from $|z-a| + |z+a| = 2ρ$ by using triangular inequality
There is an example in a book saying that by using triangular inequality for $$|z-a|+|z+a|=2ρ, z\in\mathbb{C},a\in\mathbb{C}, ρ\in\mathbb{R}$$ you get $$|a|\leqρ$$ but the steps are skipped. I tried to prove it using the triangular inequalities $$||z|-|a||\leq|z- a|\leq|z|+|a|$$ $$||z|-|a||\leq|z+a|\leq|z|+|a|$$ and then by adding them i get $$||z|-|a||\leqρ\leq|z|+|a|$$ but i can't get the book result from this. Any idea for the steps that are skipped? Thank you in advance.

Isn't the locus of all satisfying points an ellipse, which is completely inside the circle of radius $~p,~$ whose center is midway between $~\pm a ?~$  Does this type of conclusion count as using the triangle inequality?

@MartinR I don’t think this question is similar to the one you mentioned. There the inequality is given.

$$|2a| = |(z+a)-(z-a)| \le |z+a| + |z-a| = 2\rho.$$
